# Task.Run for uploading and update progress return error

Tags: c#, winforms, task-parallel-library, async-await

I have the following code that uploads a file to server and updates the progress of the upload in a bar.

```
private void UploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
    try
    {
        // get some info about the input file
        System.IO.FileInfo fileInfo = new System.IO.FileInfo(FileTextBox.Text);
        UploadDocument(fileInfo);
        // show start message
        LogText("Starting uploading " + fileInfo.Name);
        LogText("Size : " + fileInfo.Length);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LogText("Exception : " + ex.Message);
        if (ex.InnerException != null) LogText("Inner Exception : " + ex.InnerException.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        Cursor = Cursors.Default;
    }
}

private async void UploadDocument(System.IO.FileInfo fileInfo)
{
    var someTask = await Task.Run<bool>(() =>
    {
        // open input stream
        using (System.IO.FileStream stream = new System.IO.FileStream(FileTextBox.Text, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read))
        {
            using (StreamWithProgress uploadStreamWithProgress = new StreamWithProgress(stream))
            {
                uploadStreamWithProgress.ProgressChanged += uploadStreamWithProgress_ProgressChanged;

                // start service client
                FileTransferWCF.FileTransferServiceClient client = new FileTransferWCF.FileTransferServiceClient();
                //FileTransferClient.FileTransferServiceClient client = new FileTransferClient.FileTransferServiceClient();

                // upload file
                client.UploadFile(fileInfo.Name, fileInfo.Length, uploadStreamWithProgress);

                LogText("Done!");

                // close service client
                client.Close();
            }
        }

        return true;
    });
}

void uploadStreamWithProgress_ProgressChanged(object sender, StreamWithProgress.ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Length != 0)
        progressBar1.Value = (int)(e.BytesRead * 100 / e.Length);
}
```

Im getting the error: "Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'progressBar1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on." in the line:

```
progressBar1.Value = (int)(e.BytesRead * 100 / e.Length);
```

Maybe Im doing this wrong. I'm new to Task Library in .Net.

Any clue?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend reading my [`async`/`await` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html). One of the guidelines for `async` programming is to avoid `async void`; that is, use `async Task` instead of `async void` unless you're writing an event handler.

Also, once you start using `async`, try to use it everywhere. It really simplifies the code.

So, your code could be changed like this (assuming `StreamWithProgress` uses [EAP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228969.aspx) conventions):

```
private async void UploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  UploadButton.Enabled = false;
  Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
  try
  {
    // get some info about the input file
    System.IO.FileInfo fileInfo = new System.IO.FileInfo(FileTextBox.Text);
    var task = UploadDocument(fileInfo);

    // show start message
    LogText("Starting uploading " + fileInfo.Name);
    LogText("Size : " + fileInfo.Length);

    await task;

    LogText("Done!");
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    LogText("Exception : " + ex.Message);
    if (ex.InnerException != null) LogText("Inner Exception : " + ex.InnerException.Message);
  }
  finally
  {
    Cursor = Cursors.Default;
    UploadButton.Enabled = true;
  }
}

private async Task UploadDocument(System.IO.FileInfo fileInfo)
{
  // open input stream
  using (System.IO.FileStream stream = new System.IO.FileStream(FileTextBox.Text, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, 4096, true))
  { 
    using (StreamWithProgress uploadStreamWithProgress = new StreamWithProgress(stream))
    {
      uploadStreamWithProgress.ProgressChanged += uploadStreamWithProgress_ProgressChanged;

      // start service client
      FileTransferWCF.FileTransferServiceClient client = new FileTransferWCF.FileTransferServiceClient();

      // upload file
      await client.UploadFileAsync(fileInfo.Name, fileInfo.Length, uploadStreamWithProgress);

      // close service client
      client.Close();
    }
  }
}

void uploadStreamWithProgress_ProgressChanged(object sender, StreamWithProgress.ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Length != 0)
    progressBar1.Value = (int)(e.BytesRead * 100 / e.Length);
}
```

Comment: Don't you want to `await` the task you have for `UploadDocument` at some point, before the `finally` is run?

Comment: I would even think that, given the refactor, the `LogText("Done!");` really belongs in `UploadButton_Click`, thus making `UploadDocument` able to be independent of the UI (have the textbox text be another parameter) which would allow it to be moved outside of the UI class entirely, and into a worker class of some sort.

Comment: Another good point. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make UI updates on the UI thread.

```
progressBar1.Invoke(new Action(() => 
    { progressBar1.Value = (int)(e.BytesRead * 100 / e.Length); }));
```

or alternatively (if you don't want to block until the method returns)

```
progressBar1.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => 
    { progressBar1.Value = (int)(e.BytesRead * 100 / e.Length); }));
```

Apologies for the syntax, I don't have access to VS at the moment.

Comment: Even better, you can use `BeginInvoke` since you don't need to wait for the result of the invocation.

Comment: @MarekDzikiewicz so it would go like: progressBar1.BeingInvoke(new Action(() => 
    { progressBar1.Value = (int)(e.BytesRead * 100 / e.Length); })); ??

Comment: Yes, the method has the same signature, it just doesn't block until the delegate executes like `Invoke` does.